# How do I fill my password automatically from .bash_profile when running command as sudo?

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, osx, sudo

I know I could just put something like `sudo mypassword` in my `.bash_profile`, but I don't want to run every command as root.

I want password to autofill under following circumstances:

- only the commands requiring root privileges
- only commands that I explicitly state I plan to run su to root with `sudo`

Example:

```
sudo cd /var/root           #When I type this
Password:                   #I don't want to be prompted for my password
                            #I want to fill it from my `.bash_profile`
```

But:

```
cd /var/root                              #When I type this
-bash: cd: /var/root: Permission denied   #I still want this, or the like, returned
```

I saw [this post on increasing sudo timeout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10139/how-do-i-increase-sudo-password-remember-timeout), but I don't think it's quite equivalent. For example, I want it to carry across different shell log-in sessions. I could be wrong.

Any suggestions regarding what to (or not to!) add to my `.bash_profile`, or which method (`timeout vs profile`) is preferable would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What not to do? ^this^. Use `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Take care to use `visudo` to edit the sudoers file.

Comment: if your account can run `sudo` for every command without password, it is as powerful as root. If you do that you could as well run everything as root from the start.

Comment: @pqnet It's not that it wouldn't need my password - it's that it'd be read from my `.bash_profile` so I don't need to type it in. Re-read the OP as you've misunderstood my intent.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks. by use /etc/sudoers, I assume you mean just edit the timeout instead.

Comment: You don't have to use ALL. You can specify *by command* which commands require a password and which don't. Look at `man sudo` - or just read the comments in your `/etc/sudoers`. and by the way, if there is a directory on your disk into which cannot `cd` - then proably nobody should. do `ls dir` then `cat ./dir/tgt.file` stay out of there - root user or otherwise.

Comment: Another problem here is that `sudo cd /var/root` doesn't do anything useful, because a subprocess can't change the directory of its parent.

Comment: @cjm it was an example, and nothing more.

Comment: @njboot - for what its worth, I thought it was a good example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to be challenged every time for your password then I'd recommend setting it to `NOPASSWD` in your `/etc/sudoers` file rather than hardcode your password in your logins. At least this way your primary login's password will remain intact and not be completely exposed in your `.bashrc`.

To make this change run the command `sudo visudo`, and change your user accounts entry to something like this:

```
userX        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm used to using `nano` rather than `vi` but now's a good place to start. This will still require me to use sudo explicitly if I mean to run a command as root, correct? (As in, my second example - I don't want to cd to /var/root without specifying `sudo`).

Comment: @mikeserv - yup, not sure how to address that particular request. I've never heard of anything like that.

Comment: @njboot - yes this addresses your 1st bullet, your 2nd bullet, I don't think is possible, at least, I've never heard of anything that can meet that requirement, beyond listing these commands out within your sudoers file.

Comment: @slm - [one way](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html): `Cmnd_Alias ::= NAME '=' Cmnd_List NAME ::= [A-Z]([A-Z][0-9]_)*`. It is this kind of stuff, by the way, that makes `sudo` psychotic, or, at least it is *in my opinion*. You might also want to mention that `visudo` should understand the `$EDITOR` env variable - like `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano visudo`.

Comment: @mikeserv - true you can put patterns in your sudoers file, but I'd generally discourage it, just b/c it's extremely dangerous. But since he's already going w/ NOPASSWD, I guess there isn't much more harm.

Comment: @mikeserv i never would have thought of that thank you. so should i `#` my `export $EDITOR` var. from my `.bash_profile` when I proceed (i use Textmate)? Thank you all btw for all this useful information and help.

Comment: @njboot - if you want the shell's default editor to be `nano`, then, yes, `export`ing that from the shell's environment file is a good way to go about it. `vi` is POSIX specified - and the shell is even spec'd to understand its default keymaps - and so it is the baseline default editor in almost all cases.